# What is $0^0$? Should we define $0^0$ on its correctness or convenience?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, education

**What is $0^0$ ?**

I have read many debates about this question.
The debate has been going on at least since the early 19th century. At that time, most mathematicians agreed that $0^0$ = 1, until in 1821 Cauchy  listed $0^0$ along with expressions like $\frac{0}{0}$ in a table of undefined forms.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0%5E0#Zero_to_the_zero_power), there is a thread for the same.

On [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Mathematics/What-is-math-0-0-math), i read a discussion about the same.

> The question is not to explain for $0^0$=1 or $0^0$=0 or it is undefined.
>
> What sholuld we conclude for defining $0^0$ ?

Comment: ^That was Cauchy. Atleast when you can't give an answer, spell that great mathematician's name properly.

Comment: It depends how you come to $0^0$. Is it a limit case of a sequence $\{a_n^{b^n}\}$ with $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and $b_n \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: Symbols don't mean things unless we give them meaning.

Comment: So, mathematically it is not defined.

Comment: @sdcvvc: there stas needs an explanation for the question to why 0^0=1?

Comment: No, I did not say it is not defined. It is defined differently in different contexts for very good reasons, in some contexts it is not defined, and these reasons **are** explained in the link that sdcvvc gave. (I do not know what the word "stas" means.)

Comment: @anon: "stas" is the person who have asked for the explanation to 0^0=1 in that link.

Comment: @Manoj: Please see the answers in the link, not only the question.

Comment: Just going through them.